# Hashtag ajax not working consistently

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am following [this](http://css-tricks.com/examples/DynamicPage/) page to make an ajax site. It's fairly straight-forward, but the problem I am running into is that the links, which are just

```
   <a href="link.html">Link</a>
```

tend to go ignore the hashtag change and go straight to the link.html page causing a reload instead of using ajax to update the content.

When I hit the back button, the ajax part works and then when I click links from there it works - any idea what's causing this behaviour when the page is first landed on?

I am using a navigator menu from jQuery UI, if you need any more info, let me know and I'll post it asap.

Thanks for the help!

Here's the dynamic.js file that is controlling the ajax behaviour:

```
$(function() {

    var newHash      = "",
        $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
        $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
        baseHeight   = 0,
        $el;

    $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
    baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

    $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        if (newHash) {
            $mainContent
                .find("#guts")
                .fadeOut(200, function() {
                    $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                        $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                            $pageWrap.animate({
                                height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                            });
                        });
                        $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                        $("nav a[href='"+newHash+"']").addClass("current");
                    });
                });
        };

    });

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

Comment: Anything in the error console that could cause the javascript to fail and allow the `<a>` to complete?

Comment: I'm using bluefish and I testing in firefox/ie and I wish there was something out of the ordinary in the error console - just the typical css stuff you'd expect

Comment: Hmm that is weird, everything looks to match up between your page and the example page...I'll keep looking though

Comment: DId you see the problem when you scrolled to the page? I hope it's not just my laptop

Comment: Actually, if you view the source of the page, you have the code that does this: `$( "#menu" ).menu({ });` and inside of it you have `location.href = link.attr( "href" );` - I wouldn't be surprised if that's overriding it.

Comment: Yeah, I see the problem. Although I can't reproduce the whole back button situation...not important though

Comment: Good grief, that was it! THANKS for that @Ian, I thought it might have been some conflict with the js from the menu

Comment: Haha no problem. I added an answer that outlines the problem :) Glad I could help find the "problem"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I view the source of the page, you have the code that does this:

```
$( "#menu" ).menu({

});
```

and inside of it, you have:

```
location.href = link.attr( "href" );
```

I have a feeling that since this is executing it in addition to your `hashchange` handling, it's being called and overriding (in whatever way) the AJAX loading stuff. It might work if you remove/comment the line, but make sure your site is still functioning as you want after you make this change.

Comment: yep, removing `location.href = link.attr( "href" );` from my js menu solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using preventDefault() when assigning the click event to the links?

```
$("nav").delegate("a", "click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });
```

return false should do the job but just to be sure

Comment: Not a bad idea, but if you look at the docs page for `delegate`, there's plenty of places that show that `return false` prevents default behavior and stops the propagation, as does returning false from all/most jQuery event handlers. And the fact that the script works fine on the example page the OP got it from makes me think using `preventDefault` directly wouldn't have an effect, as the OP almost completely copy/pasted the code.

Comment: Thanks for the input stratton - when I removed the line from the menu's js, it stopped the override and solved the problem. Thanks for the input, I'll keep it for future reference!